# regular expression to extract numerical values

Tags: python, regex

I have a python line of code to extract the numerical values from a data:

```
for line in infile:
    line = line.strip()
    m = re.findall('^[\S*]|[\#*].*([0-9.]+)', line)
    print m
```

Data to extract:

```
Sombry23                        083_13A
# spiserg (>= 20 ma)            80
Anumm Lowess (>= 20 ma)         1971621
# someure                       80
Lomwer Spisers                  147719
Assime Suree                    1971621
Starrduss Murgge                2007491
MR (%)                          41.30
Remanoweq MR (%)                41.30
X90                             69829
```

Expected result (tab-separated):

```
083_13A 80  1971621 80  147719  1971621 2007491 41.30   41.30   69829
```

How can I modify this code to get the expected output?

Comment: How is `"083_13A"` numerical data? For capturing a number at the end of a string, `r'([\d.]+)$'` will work.

Comment: How about `line[32:]` (extract a substring)?

Comment: what's the current output?

Comment: Isn't this enough: https://regex101.com/r/oB3yC6/1 ?

Comment: forget regex, you can do `line = line.split("    ")[-1].strip()`

Comment: Does your "expected output" purposefully include the numbers from the commented lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print '\t'.join([line.strip().split()[-1] for line in infile])
```

Comment: Thanks to Amit and everyone for your help and time. Amit's solution worked fine. Solution Problem now solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanna do it using regular expressions here's one way.

```
list = []
for line in infile:
    list.append(re.search(r"^.*\s(.+)$",line).group(1))
print "\t".join(list)
```

Although amit's answer is much cleaner